# add dependency to subdirectory in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm building a project in CMake.
I have to build a build utility to build a program, which has to be included with add_subdirectory().

As an example,
file structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
program.c
...
buildutils
└ util
  ├ util.c
  └ CMakeLists.txt
```

Can I write the script that builds all of the subdirectories in directory buildutils, and build program.c with a dependency of directory buildutils?

Comment: I understand `program` is not linking `buildutils` so I would go for `add_dependencies(program builduitils)` here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html

Comment: @rturrado - don't link to outdated CMake docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, The question was about how can I add a dependency to a project in a subdirectory.